# Can we use a signle ionic-4 app for mobile and desktops

Tags: ionic4

I am developing an `ionic-4` app, `Ionic` provides **cross platform apps** but I am a bit confused and my confusion is can I use a single `ionic-4 application` for `mobiles(e.g. Android and IOS)` and `desktops browsers(Chrome, firefox etc.)` as website. Is it possible by using `ionic version 4.`

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ionic 4 provides a single code for the execution of multiple platforms.

[Ionic Doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/browser-support)

here is help for you. You can check everything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Ionic for Android, IOS and Browser. Once the coding is done, you can add any platform  to make its build. For example, if you add Android platform then you can take an Android build(APK).Before that  you need to setup an environment for that . For example, you need Android studio for taking Android build and Xcode for taking IOS build. It's all depends on the platform that you use.
Please go through Ionic documentation and Youtube tutorials to get a correct picture.

Thank you